# Forgot to add STO hours and activated the journey

Tags: journeybuilder, einstein, einstein-sto

I forgot to add STO period and activated the journey, what will happen now ?

Answer (score 0):

The emails/text messages will send in sequence respecting wait time and other journey logic.